# "Redaction marks" with pdfbox Java api

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am looking to create redaction marks in pdf using pdfbox. The generated pdf with redaction marks will be used to make redactions in acrobat pdf reader.

Is it possible to create Redaction marks using pdfbox Java api.

Sample code would be much helpful.

Comment: It's not possible currently, i.e. there are no appropriate classes. One might do it with the COS classes after reading and understanding the PDF specification ("12.5.6.23 Redaction Annotations"). I could implement such classes later this year if somebody comes up with a few sample PDFs.

Comment: In other words, it is possible nowadays using lowlevel APIs, there merely is not yet a highlevel API for redaction marks in PDFBox. If you know the internals of the PDF format, therefore, you can create redaction marks with PDFBox; otherwise, you should wait until @Tilman or some other kind soul implements the high level API.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found such feature in python module PyMuPDF. It has apis to make all types of highlights and redactions.

Comment: Note: PyMuPDF is AGPL license. Not free.